# Safari rendering of website, very different from firefox .

Tags: css, html

I built this site chrisbrundige.me ; It looks great in firefix on my laptop and almost perfect on mobile, excluding iphone. the desktop version of safari also looks awful. What can i do to fix it ?

Comment: Please go check https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 0):

maybe take into consideration css prefixes:

Mozilla uses -moz-
Chrome/Opera/Safari use -webkit-
Microsoft uses -ms-